# QList with nested types isn't shown properly in VS debugger

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, visual-studio-2008, qt5

`QList<foo>` is shown properly in debugger, however, a nested struct like `QList<foo::bar>` is not.

For example, for this code:

```
struct foo { struct bar { int var; }; };
struct bar { int var; };
...
QList<foo::bar> list1;
QList<bar> list2;
...
```

This is what the debugger would show:

[image]

**Note:** I already had to edit the autoexp.dat to show QVector properly, because there seems to be a bug in the QT addin for VS that doesn't set them up properly for Qt5.

So is there a way to fix that (by editing autoexp.dat/something else)?

Answer (score 0):

Move to Visual Studio 2010, this will fix your problem:

[image]